# Multidimensional FourierCoefficient, how to do / how to get as discrete deltas

Tags: simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to turn a pretty nasty differential equation into a spectral form. And while I have done most of the work by hand, I want to check my work with Mathematica.

One step I need is the fourier series of a external potential. If I have something simple like

```
FourierCoefficient[Cos[x]*Cos[y],{x,y},{n,m}]
```

It gives me 0

What I'd expect to get is

```
1/4 (m==-1 || m==+1) && (n==-1 || n==+1)
```

I get the correct answer when I do

```
FourierCoefficient[Cos[y]*FourierCoefficient[Cos[x],x,n],y,m]
```

But that is cumbersome since I need to manually split the terms. It does not scale when I have a long and complicated expression. Has anybody had this problem before? Do you know how I can fix it?

Lastly, It would be much more convenient if I can turn

```
1/4 (m==-1 || m==+1) && (n==-1 || n==+1)
```

Into something like

```
1/4 (DiscreteDelta[m-1] + DiscreteDelta[m+1]) * (DiscreteDelta[n-1] + DiscreteDelta[n+1])
```

or more preferebly

```
1/4 (KroneckerDelta[m,1] + KroneckerDelta[m,-1]) * (KroneckerDelta[n,1] + KroneckerDelta[n,-1])
```

Does anyone know of any functions or shortcuts I can use to turn the AND and OR outputs into a more suitable format?

Thank You!

Edit: Thanks for your feedback, it seems like this is a bug in Mathematica and I submitted a bug report. Also, I did not submit the whole output for the second expression, technically it was this.

```
FourierCoefficient[Cos[y]*FourierCoefficient[Cos[x],x,n],y,m]
```

> \begin{cases}  \frac{1}{4} & (m=-1 || m=1) \&\& (n=-1||n=1) \\  0
> & \text{True} \end{cases}

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! The first part definitely seems like a deeper bug in `Integrate` for dealing with symbolic values, as when we evaluate `Assuming[{m, n} \[Element] Integers, (1/2 Pi)^2 Integrate[Cos[t1] Cos[t2] Exp[-I (n t1 - m t2)], {t1, -Pi, Pi}, {t2, -Pi, Pi}]]`, one gets `0`; but when we replace `m` or `n` with e.g. `1` and `-1`, we get what we expected to. Sorry I don't have a general solution—maybe someone here does! In any case it should definitely be [reported as a bug.](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=Feedback)

Comment: Also note that the full output is not an output of and's and or's, but a `Piecewise` function, and that I think you accidentally didn't copy the full expression! One can turn `KroneckerDelta`'s into `Piecewise` functions via `PiecewiseExpand`, but a function would have to be written to try to go the other way—I don't think there's a built-in way. Still possible, though!

Comment: Try: `Table[FourierCoefficient[Cos[x]*Cos[y], {x, y}, {m, n}], {m, -1, 
  1}, {n, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber : Thank you Daniel, that works great for my specific case, however, if the coefficients are nonzero at higher modes I would need to know what range to search in. (say Cos[16 x] or something less obvious like Cos[x]*Sin[x]). It becomes difficult for more complicated expressions.

Comment: With a little knowledge of  circular functions, guessing the range is not difficult? Cos[16x] should be obvious. And also Cos[x] Sin[x],  that comes from Sin[2x]